# What am I doing wrong trying to debug Angular in VSCode using the attach method?

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code

I created the following .bat file and placed it in startup, and it appears to be running because Chrome is starting up after a restart.  I'd placed pause lines in it to make sure everything was working correctly and manually ran it first:

```
cd\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

I use ng serve to successfully start the application.  Here's my launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9222,
        "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Yet when I try to run the attach process (with Chrome Debugging extension installed), I get this old gem:

[image: Error]

Note that vscode has the folder open that contains the folders .vscode, e2e, node_modules, src etc.

I had this working at a previous job but I can't remember what I might be missing.

After coming across a similar question, I tried using `"urlFilter": "http://localhost:4200/*",` instead of URL, killing all Chrome processes and running the .bat file again just to be sure, and STILL no luck.

Comment: You're trying to debug JavaScript by attaching to Chrome? Try opening the console in the browser. Otherwise, we'll need more information on what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Sometimes it happens to me, usually the first time I run it. I then cancel and run it again. I think is because my computer is busy processing other stuff, and then timeout occurs. Sometimes having Chrome open helps.

Answer (score 0):

Go to vscode debug mode and once you click on run it will give you options to configure various debug modes. Select your configuration and run it. Go through the vscode keys list. Also try to change the port number